# Frustrated with cUrl and Windows and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, curl, libcurl

I am trying to install `curb` gem for rails for 2 hours. My curlib doesn't work even if i downloaded everything, put in enviromental path, but still i am getting error

```
extconf.rb:23:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curb != libcurl.  You need to install libcurl separately.  You can [download](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) the zip file from the curl website and extract to whatever directory you want.  If you have trouble, read the documentation [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html).

I would suggest that you install some flavor of linux virtually, or just dual boot.  This won't be the last headache you have from running rails on windows.